# cURL - How to make cURL sessions/cookies behave the same as a regular web browser?

Tags: curl

My goal here is to able to access a site via cURL. I want cURL to match what a regular browsers does to access a page.

I have been trying to compare sessions when using cURL (using a cookiejar) and using a regular browser. This is the code I use to ensure that cURL is using cookies and sessions

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiejar_filename);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiejar_filename);
```

However, after inspecting the contents of the Cookiejar file and using a regular browser and inspecting the headers via Firebug, it seems to me that the the Cookiejar is different, or at least incomplete

*Cookiejar*

```
www.a-site.com  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  55E82598EF3284F374F58CA6DC8C11FE.JP_DC2PR_11
www.a.site.com  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   Desktop Yes
```

*Browser*

```
ns_cookietest=true; __utma=113861848.1832854207.1369452081.1370916912.1370920751.11; __utmz=113861848.1369452081.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); _ga=1.3.1832854207.1369452081; tc_cj_v2=%5Ecl_%5Dny%5B%5D%5D_mmZZZZZZKMQJRMMNMOMMMZZZ%5D777_rn_lh%5BfyfcheZZZ222H%22**%22%27%20H%7D*%28H+%23ZZZKMQJRMNQKMNPPZZZ%5D777%5Ecl_%5Dny%5B%5D%5D_mmZZZZZZKMQJSLJQNSLRKZZZ%5D; dotcarClient="AKLC01|AKLC01|oc_br|18/06/2013 09:00|25/06/2013 09:00|NZ"; _wt.user-325805=WT3KC0StLfCnd6A4ur2nAUdXBJ9Ez7OOCDiLTqV0IYdywEaF1kd6x1mPEuy8yFjYdeay2CrS9sn1yAo205C-EW_mQAxZzyF5Zmn7It9h_v4C6w~; JSESSIONID=55E82598EF3284F374F58CA6DC8C11FE.JP_DC2PR_08; Desktop=Yes; __utmc=113861848; ns_cookietest=true; ns_session=true; _wt.mode-325805=WT3_vlvsvnZ9Lk~; __utmb=113861848.2.10.1370920751
```

If you inspect and compare both of these information, you will see that the "JSESSIONID" and "Desktop" data are present, but the Cookiejar file is lacking the other data.

Is there a way to make cURL sessions/cookies behave the same as a regular web browser?